# How to track location consistently in the background on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, core-location

We implemented a functionality that tracks the user location on the background at least every 15 minutes. At the moment the background tracking works great for a couple of hours, some cases up until 8 hours, and other cases can go up to 6 days.

The issue is that at a certain point while the user is **stationary** the app stops managing the location updates for no apparent reason, and reopening the application will not resume the tracking process. We know that the app is not managing the location updates because the device logs show an event from **locationd** sending the position to our app, but there's no code execution.

We understand that the OS at any time can terminate the application, but we would like to be able to manage those cases to correctly communicate this behavior to the user that expects tracking to keep functioning or for the tracking to continue sending locations in the background.

> This issue seems to be inconsistent across our user base, we've identified that users with iOS 14.4+ and from the iPhone 8 up to the iPhone 13 present this problem.

Our current configuration for the location manager is:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate
Location *geoData;
-   (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   ///...
   if (geoData == nil) {
      geoData = [Location sharedInstance];
   }
   ///...
}
-   (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
   geoData = nil;
}
```

**Location.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**Location.m**

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];

if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) 
{
   [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {
   _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}

_locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
_locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

We receive the updates through the **didUpdateLocations** where we send the data to an external API server.

The app is configured with **Background fetch** and **Location updates** background modes.

Comment: Has your app received the upgrade from provisional always to always location permission?  Using automotive navigation activity type with nearest kilometre accuracy is an odd combination. It sounds like significant location change monitoring might be a better match for your use case; it will relaunch a jettisoned app while standard location dates won't. You should check the analytics data available under privacy in your device settings for app jettison logs; your app may be exhausting the allowed background execution time.  If the user doesn't open your app it won't keep running forever.

Comment: The problem is replicable while the always location permission is upgraded correctly. I’ll test using the significant location change monitor, I found the [part of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background) that describes the behavior that you mentioned and sounds promising. Thanks